# how to flatten multiple array in hive

Tags: hive, hadoop2

My data has 2 arrays (may have different size) like so:

```
    {  
  "depotCode":"0001",
  "in":[  
    {  
      "partCode":"AX-01",
      "qty":15
    },
    {  
      "partCode":"AX-02",
      "qty":77
    },
    {  
      "partCode":"AX-03",
      "qty":100
    }      ],
  "out":[  
    {  
      "partCode":"AX-01",
      "qty":7
    },
    {  
      "partCode":"TB-77",
      "qty":5
    }
  ]
}
```

and expected result looks like this:

```
depotCode,partCode,in,out
0001,AX-01,15,7
0001,AX-02,77,0
0001,AX-03,100,0
0001,TB-77,0,5
```

what's the efficient hive query for this?
if you notice, since AX-01 is present in both "in" and "out", then the value is non-zero for both field.
as for the other, either one is zero

PS: if possible, I need this done in a single query and efficiently since we have more than a billion rows already (so subquery that may be slow should be avoided, unless subquery is somehow not slow in hive or spark, etc)

Comment: Can you tell me the presentation of this data from hive table. select * from hiveTable. I can write the query by visualizing from there.

Comment: the json comes from legacy couchDB. it's stored as json in couchDB in exactly that format, but I removed irrelevant fields for simplicity

Answer (score 0):

@srilanka_ratnapura; use concat_ws function

here is a documentation about it: http://www.folkstalk.com/2011/11/string-functions-in-hive.html

```
Example: 
select concat_ws(',', col1, col2, col3, col4) from tbl 
Returns:
     col1,col2,col3,col4
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.